# Make a span align to the bottom of another span next to a div in a horizontal line

Tags: html, css

(I know that the title is vague but I seriously had no clue on how I could explain this in a sentence.)
I'm trying to line up elements inside a div in a certain way without success. Basically, I'm making a checkout cart layout that should look like this: [image]

But this is what it ends up looking like with my current code:

[image]

The code:

```css
    #shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child {
      display: block;
      color: #000000;
      float: right;
      line-height: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .shopping_cart .more_info {
      color: #000;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name {
      color: #000000;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 7px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name:before {
      content: "\f07a";
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 10px;
      float: none;
      padding: 0px;
      color: #000000;
    }
    
    #shopping_cart_container .ajax_cart_quantity {
      font-size: 33px;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: left;
    }
    
    #shopping_cart_container .more_info .ajax_cart_product_txt,
    .ajax_cart_product_txt_s,
    .ajax_cart_total {
      float: left;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .invisible {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="shopping_cart_container">
      <div class="shopping_cart">
        <a href="http://localhost/Checkout" title="Checkout" rel="nofollow">
          <span class="cart_name"></span>
          <div class="more_info">
            <span class="ajax_cart_quantity">1</span>
            <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt">Product</span>
            <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt_s invisible">Products (shows when there is more than 1 item)</span>
            <span class="ajax_cart_total">$99</span>
            <span class="ajax_cart_no_product invisible">Empty (shows when there are no items in cart)</span>
          </div>
          <div class="cartSummary invisible">Cart Summary that shows when hovered over</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9yegcku/)

I apologize in advance if the code is a mess but as you can see, I've messed around with `float` quite a bit in order to try to align it all correctly. I've hit a brick wall here so I'd appreciate any pointers!

Comment: try removing the `clear: both` from `.ajax_cart_total {
      float: left;
      clear: both;
    }`. This will make it inline.

Comment: @Envision If I do that then "Product" and the price will be inline as well. I want the price under the "Product" span while still keeping the rest inline. (See my layout reference in my original post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this

```css
#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  float: right;
  line-height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shopping_cart .more_info {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name:before {
  content: "\f07a";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}

.product_block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product_block span.ajax_cart_product_txt {
  display: block;
}

.checkout_button {
  background: #333;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

#shopping_cart_container .ajax_cart_quantity {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="shopping_cart_container">
  <div class="shopping_cart">
    <a href="http://localhost/Checkout" title="Checkout" rel="nofollow">
      <span class="cart_name"></span>
      <div class="more_info">
        <span class="ajax_cart_quantity">1</span>
        <div class="product_block">
          <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt">Product</span>
          <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt_s invisible">Products (shows when there is more than 1 item)</span>
          <span class="ajax_cart_total">$99.99</span>
          <span class="ajax_cart_no_product invisible">Empty (shows when there are no items in cart)</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="checkout_button">
        Checkout
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="cartSummary invisible">Cart Summary that shows when hovered over</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suppose it does the work, I wrapped the "product" & "price" in a div to manage it independently from the other span.

Comment: I was hesitant to edit the HTML part since it's tangled up in quite the mess. It did indeed work, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this helps.

```css
#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child {

  color: #000000;
  float: right;
  line-height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shopping_cart .more_info {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#shopping_cart_container .shopping_cart > a:first-child span.cart_name:before {
  content: "\f07a";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  
  
  float: middle;
 
  color: #000000;
}

#shopping_cart_container .ajax_cart_quantity {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#shopping_cart_container .more_info .ajax_cart_product_txt,
.ajax_cart_product_txt_s,
.ajax_cart_total {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.product-cost{
  float: right;
}
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="shopping_cart_container">
  <div class="shopping_cart">
    <a href="http://localhost/Checkout" title="Checkout" rel="nofollow">
      <span class="cart_name"></span>
      <div class="more_info">
        <span class="ajax_cart_quantity">1</span>
        <div class = "product-cost">
        <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt">Product</span>
        <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt_s invisible">Products (shows when there is more than 1 item)</span>
        <span class="ajax_cart_total">$99</span>
        </div>
        <span class="ajax_cart_no_product invisible">Empty (shows when there are no items in cart)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="cartSummary invisible">Cart Summary that shows when hovered over</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess wrapping it in an another div is the only solution, but hey it works. Thank you as well!

Comment: Can't mark two answers unfortunately. I upvoted though!